# Collection View Cell Won't Allow Me to Select

Tags: xcode, collectionview

This is probably a really easy fix; I have been reading countless forums and tutorials and can't seem to find answer.

In my app I have a popover collection view to select a specific option and return a value...

However it won't highlight or select? I can see the NS Log Outputs never show a selection or datapass.

Here is my code...

collection.h file

```
@interface collection : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource,     UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray  *counterImages;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray  *descriptions;
@property (nonatomic, weak)   UILabel *graniteselect;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController* _collectionPopOver;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear; // defaults to YES, and if    YES, any selection is cleared in viewWillAppear:
@property (nonatomic) BOOL allowsSelection;

@end


implementation file:



#pragma mark UICollectionViewDataSource

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return _descriptions.count;

}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MyCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImage *image;
int row = [indexPath row];

image = [UIImage imageNamed:_counterImages[row]];

myCell.imageView.image = image;

myCell.celltext.text= [_descriptions objectAtIndex:row];

return myCell;
```

}

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView performAction:(SEL)action        forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
{
_graniteselect.text = [_descriptions objectAtIndex:row];
 [self._collectionPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

NSLog(@"Setting Value for Granite Select");
```

}

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// TODO: Deselect item
}



-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
RoleDetailTVC *destination =
[segue destinationViewController];

destination.graniteselect = _graniteselect;

NSLog(@"Passing Data to RoleDetailTVC");

}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of issues here. Firstly, I think you mixed up the delegate methods for selection. The `collectionView:performAction:forItemAtIndexPath:withSender:` method is only for special menu popovers and has nothing to do with selecting a cell *per se*. What you need to implement in your delegate is this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Selected cell at index path %@", indexPath);
}
```

right now you're just implementing the **deselect** callback.

Beyond that, also make sure that your image view in the `UICollectionViewCell` has touches enabled, otherwise you might be blocking touch events to reach the cell and it won't fire any delegate calls. I hope that helps!